# Have you tested Check Point Endpoint Security or Disknet Pro?

Tags: security

I have to secure the removable media devices that get connected to a system. The costumer has proposed to use Check Point Endpoint Security, (formerly Disknet Pro, I think) because they used successfully Disknet Pro in some projects in the past. I would like to have some feedback about this tool, its ease of use, ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ease of use is not something you whant to put in the same sentence as CP Endpointsecurity (oops just did - but that´s ok?!). I´ve seen projects involving Disknet Pro go down because of the complexity.

For disk and device encryption I would recommend [True Crypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). It´s not only opensource but pretty straight forward and works great for me and some of my clients (Diskencryption for 40+ Notebooks...)

Answer (score 0):

Having worked as QA engineer for the Reflex Disknet Pro product, i would say that it does exactly what it says on the tin.

Ease of use however, once its set up and configured, its pretty straight forward but building encryption profiles for users based on different levels of access required is where most of your brain power will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been supporting Pointsec/Checkpoint Media Encryption and Full Disk encrypption for 3 years. Sure you can have a few machines that fail but you need good project management and know your supported drivers and hardware platforms in advance (early!)

I have lots of customers who now manage their own servers and deployments - checkpoint support are also very good and stand up to all the other major vendors (Cisco, Juniper) when it comes to support levels.